# How to flow gradient through parameter updates?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

I have a parameter

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
x = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1.0]))
```

I need to update the value of this parameter while maintaining the gradient flow (for a meta learning problem).

PyTorch does not allow in-place operations on leaf-variable like

```
a = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad=True)
x.copy_(a)
x.backward()
>>> RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

In addition, I also tried the following, but while working, the gradient didn't flow:

```
x = nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([1.0]))
a = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad=True)
x = nn.Parameter(a)
x.backward()
print(a.grad)
>>> None
```

How can I update the value of a parameter while maintaining gradient flow?

Comment: What exactly is "maintaining gradient flow"?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/chenwydj/learning-to-learn-by-gradient-descent-by-gradient-descent) explained the problem really well (we need to update `nn.Parameters` in place while retaining the `grad_fn`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [`torch.Tensor.clone`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clone.html):

> This function ***is differentiable***, so gradients will flow back from the
> result of this operation to `input`. To create a tensor without an
> autograd relationship to input see `detach()`.

```
>>> a = torch.tensor([2.0], requires_grad=True)
>>> x = a.clone()
>>> x.backward()

>>> a.grad
tensor([1.])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I believe that to update a parameter in place we need to use something like `p.copy_`, otherwise the update wont actually take place in the working memory of `nn.Module subclass`. So something like `x = nn.Parameter(a.clone())` won't work. [This](https://github.com/chenwydj/learning-to-learn-by-gradient-descent-by-gradient-descent) explained the problem really well (we need to update `nn.Parameters` in place while retaining the `grad_fn`. In Pytorch, `nn.Parameters` are designed to be leaf nodes...). It has code which I still haven't managed to implement

Comment: Why not actually applying the inplace operator on `a`?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following. Even if we change the value of `a` inlace we still need to change the value of the `nn.Parameter` `x` inplace to update it. Unless you meant something different? Their [notebook](https://github.com/chenwydj/learning-to-learn-by-gradient-descent-by-gradient-descent/blob/master/Grad_buffer.ipynb) has a pretty good explanation (under "Implementation") and implementation, but I'm still working on figuring this out

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you give a minimal example explaining what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Apologies for the complication! It will take me a bit to simplify my code, but the main goal is to update the parameters using SGD. The update line is the issue `p.copy_(p - nn.Parameter(lr) * p._grad)`. The meta learning model needs to get the gradients (need to update nn.Parameters inplace while retaining the grad_fn of the expression). The links I added in the comments mentioned using `buffers` and creating a new `Variable` from the current variable's data, and making sure that its gradients are still kept. Hopefully this makes more sense until I can simplify my code! But let me know if not